# Convert docker image into Cloud Foundry droplet

Tags: docker, cloud, cloud-foundry

Is there a simple way of converting my **docker image** to a cloud foundry droplet ?

What did not work:

```
docker save registry/myapp1 |gzip > myapp1.tgz
cf push myapp1 --droplet myapp1.tgz
LOG:    2021-02-13T12:36:28.80+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
LOG:    2021-02-13T12:36:28.80+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR /tmp/lifecycle/launcher: no start command specified or detected in droplet
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your docker image on Cloud Foundry, simply run `cf push -o <your/image>`. Cloud Foundry can natively run docker images so long as your operations team has enabled that functionality ([not a lot of reason to disable it](https://docs.pivotal.io/application-service/2-10/adminguide/docker.html#multi-tenant)) and [you meet the requirements](https://docs.pivotal.io/application-service/2-10/adminguide/docker.html#run-monitor).

You can check to see if Docker support is enabled by running `cf feature-flag` and looking for the line `diego_docker enabled`. If it says `disabled`, talk to your operations team about enabling it.

By doing this, you don't need to do any complicated conversion. The image is just run directly on Cloud Foundry.

This doesn't 100% answer your question, but it's what I would recommend if at all possible.

---

To try and answer your question, I don't think there's an easy way to make this conversion. The output of `docker save` is a bunch of layers. This is not the same as a droplet which is an archive containing some specific folders (app bits + what's installed by your buildpacks). I suppose you could convert them, but there's not a clear path to doing this.

The way Cloud Foundry uses a droplet is different and more constrained than a Docker image. The droplet gets extracted into `/home/vcap` overtop of an Ubuntu Bionic (`cflinuxfs3` root filesystem) and the app is then run out of there. This your droplet can only contain files that will go into this one place in the file system.

For a Docker image, you can literally have a completely custom file system.

So given that difference, I don't think there's a generic way you can take a random docker image and convert that to a droplet. The best you could probably do is take some constrained set of docker images, like those build from Ubuntu Bionic, using certain patterns, extract the files necessary to run your app, stuff them directories that will unpack overtop of `/home/vcap` (i.e. that resembles a droplet), tar gzip it and try to use that.

Starting with the output of `docker save` is probably a good idea. You'd then just need to extract the files you want from the tar archive of the layers (i.e. dig through each layer, which is another tar archive and extract files), then move them into a directory structure that resembles this:

```
./
./deps/
./profile.d/
./staging_info.yml
./tmp/
./logs/
./app/
```

where `./deps` is typically where buildpacks will install required dependencies, `./.profile.d/` is where you can put scripts that will run before your app starts and `./app` is where your app (most of your files) will end up.

The `staging_info.yml`, I'm not 100% sure is required, but basically breaks down to `{"detected_buildpack":"java","start_command":""}`. You could fake the `detected_buildpack` setting it to anything and then `start_command` is obviously the command to run (you can override this later though).

I haven't tried doing this because `cf push -o` is much easier, but you could give it a shot if `cf push -o` isn't an option.